# How would a DynamoDB table be structured for event based data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, storage, analytics

I am pretty new to DynamoDB but I am trying to get more familiar with AWS and its services.

For my use-case, I am wanting to store app based events in DynamoDB and mainly use BI to visualize the data, however it is likely I will end up doing some CRUD operations as well.

The data I want to store would have a userId, an eventName, and different events will have different attributes that I want to store as well.

So, a user can have multiple events with the same name and each event can have multiple dynamic attributes. We could have an endless amount of different event names as well.

Example event:

> const event = {
> userId: userId,
> eventName: 'some_event',
> data: {
> //any attributes
> }
> }

Answer (score 1):

With Dynamodb and designing its setup it is most important to know your *access patterns* for how you plan to access the data in the future.  The only thing that is required on any document into a dynamo is its partition (hash) key (aka your pk) - even its sort (range) key (aka, sk) is optional. And all attributes are completely optional and can be 100% different from every other entry if you wanted.

However, because this is NOT an an sql db and once you get to large sets of data trying to filter scans and try to look up data by information that is not part of your PK/SK combination is extremely costly and time consuming. You want to design the data storage in such a way that will give you the ability to pull up whatever you need with a single *query* and that requires *knowing* its PK and at least a part of its SK.

So, ask yourself with your event - how do you plan on looking up that data? is it always going to be by userId? if you are always going to have your userID to look up the data then that makes a fine sk. but if you may need to look up data at some point by some method other than user ID you have to either have an Index or some other duplication of data (which is *fine* please realize that in Dynamo having the same data duplicated across multiple documents is OK - writes are MUCH easier and usually much cheaper than complex reads.)

If your 'some event' is how you plan on organizing your data then that makes a possible part of your SK - maybe your PK is your userID and your sk's are each event name with an ISO8601 date after it (say `Login#2021-02-28-12:45:55.55T00:00` )  - you would then be able to look up all the logins for a given userID by querying the pk of userID and sk begins with Login

but lets say you want to look up every login from every user between x and y times.  You'll need to do either one of two strategies - create an Index, or duplicate the data by also including a document whose PK is Login and SK is userID#ISO8601 Date. There are pro's and cons too both.

Pros - much easier with an inverted index flipping the responsibility of the pk and sk. Cons - There is a delay in data replication to index's, so you may end up missing the most recent data

Duplicating the data has the pro of being always up to date with a con of needing 2 writes and potentially having even more data in your table than you need - but given the manner in which Dynamo works, thats actually not that big a con if your PK/SK setup is robust enough.

**So basically the answer is:** Figure out your access patterns and go from there. Reading between the lines of your post I would say that a PK of userID and an SK of EventName#ISO8601-Date + an Index that flips the pk/sk would be your best bet. OR, if you plan on doing aggregate data mostly, then flip that to EventName as pk and userID#ISO8601-Date as your SK with an inverted index as that would be more up to date data on aggregate analytics across all users, as the other way would be more up to date per user.